# How to start a loader when a postback happens,then after that loader should be stopped in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

When a user clicks the Export button while I triggered loader event to start loader. which method has done on the client side using jquery. a postback happens where I will have generated a large number of PDF documents from HTML string using itextsharp.
after all, generated all those files zipped and download in the client browser.

I do the following:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.zip");
    Response.TransmitFile(zipPath);
```

Since could not able to stop that loader after downloaded.

server-side code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = GetImportDetailsPDF("ImportFile(2)_2017.12.19-12.30.24.xlsx");
    //Generated all pdf files zipped and downloaded here
    string startPath = Server.MapPath("/ImportPdf/");
    string zipPath = Server.MapPath("/ImportZip/result.zip");

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=output.zip");
    Response.TransmitFile(zipPath);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}

public string GetImportDetailsPDF(string FileName)
{

    return "Successfully Imported";
}
```

Comment: What blocking tool are you using... And how is it initiated... jQuery blockui,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following **client-side solution** based on [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx) class:

```
<!-- language: html -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(prm_InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(prm_EndRequest);
        function prm_InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
            //show screen blocker
        }
        function prm_EndRequest(sender, args) {
            //hide screen blocker after a file is generated
            //DoClick to download a prepared file
        }
    </script>
```

Using an UpdatePanel you can have a very smooth solution: your end-users won't see any postback attributes until file download starts.

You can find a detailed description of this approach and see the this solution in action [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2293/how-to-show-aspxloadingpanel-during-export).